# Сжатие данных на node.js средствами express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Есть небольшое приложение rest на node.js. Пытаюсь сжимать данные json, которые возвращаю по различным путям, но  ничего не сжимается. Использую express и compression.

```
var express = require('express');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var compression = require('compression');

var app = express();
app.use(compression());

app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(serveStatic('public', {'index': ['index.html']}));
app.use('/', require('./routes'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
});

app.disable('x-powered-by');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
});
```

По запросу api возвращает следующий заголовок

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3756
ETag: W/"56IqvwOVCBB3MRndvDsFTA=="
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 14:21:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: В загловках ЗАПРОСА есть заголовок `Accept-Encoding` со значением `deflate` или `gzip` ?

Comment: Нет, в заголовке запроса нет данного значения. Обязательно ли оно должно быть это значени? Не достаточно сжать данные и передать это в заголовке ответа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль compression сжимает данные только тогда, когда клиент поддерживает контент в gzip или deflate. Для того, чтобы показать, что клиент поддерживает gzip/deflate, нужно передавать соответствующие значение в заголовке `Accept-Encoding`.

Comment: А можно не посылать с клиента Accept-Encoding. Использовать сжатие на сервере, я такое делал на iis и apache. Тоже самое на node.js хотелось бы повторить, возможно нужно использовать другую библиотеку.

Comment: @kamerrer попробуйте перегрузить функцию [.filter](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#filter-1). Но вообще это не самая хорошая практика, не по REST.